# How encrypt and decrypt several values in a row

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

In my programm I use [crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/) library.
I have so struct:

```
struct crypt_struct{
  //consists of encrypted data
  string name1;
  string name2;
  string name3;
}
struct decrypt_struct{
  //consists of decrypted data
  int name1;
  string name2;
  double name3;
}
```

I have encrypt function:

```
crypt_struct encrypt(decrypt_struct struct_in) {
    //Key and IV setup
    //AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
    //bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
    //begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes
    byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH], iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    //output encrypt struct
    crypt_struct struct_out;

    //encrypt text
    string ciphertext;

    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));


    //int name1
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> ((to_string(struct_in.name1)).c_str()), (to_string(struct_in.name1)).length() + 1);
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    struct_out.name1 = ciphertext;
    cout << ciphertext << endl;
    ciphertext.clear();

    //string name2
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (struct_in.name2.c_str()), struct_in.name2.length() + 1);
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    struct_out.name2 = ciphertext;
    cout << ciphertext << endl;
    ciphertext.clear();

    //double name3
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> ((to_string(struct_in.name3)).c_str()), (to_string(struct_in.name3)).length() + 1);
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    struct_out.name3 = ciphertext;
    cout << ciphertext << endl;
    ciphertext.clear();

    return struct_out;
}
```

And decrypt function:

```
decrypt_struct decrypt(crypt_struct struct_in)
{
    //Key and IV setup
    //AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
    //bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
    //begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes

    byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH], iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    //
    // Decrypt
    //
    decrypt_struct struct_out;
    string decryptedtext;
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedtext));

    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(struct_in.name1.c_str()), struct_in.name1.length());
    struct_out.name1= atoi(decryptedtext.c_str());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    decryptedtext.clear();

    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(struct_in.name2.c_str()), struct_in.name2.length());
    struct_out.name2= atoi(decryptedtext.c_str());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    decryptedtext.clear();

    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(struct_in.name3.c_str()), struct_in.name3.length());
    struct_out.name3= atoi(decryptedtext.c_str());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    decryptedtext.clear();

    return struct_out;
```

}

If I try encrypt only one variable, then everything is decrypted correctly. But if I try to encrypt several variables at the same time, then an error occurs. And moreover, when encrypting the variable int type, the same error occurs. With what it can be connected, is there anyone's idea?

It seems to me that perhaps the reason is that at a time this function can only encrypt one line.

Comment: I am not all that familiar with `crypto++` but storing encrypted data in a `C++` string seems a little dangerous since it will append a `\0` - and the encrypted data itself may contain a null terminator in the middle - so `c_str` may not return the correct representation when attempting to decrypt the data - using a byte/char buffer would be much safer.

Comment: @Prediluted, I'm not sure about this, so I tried to implement everything in accordance with the source code of this library.

Comment: You should be able to decrypt the results to a `std::string` - but you will most certainly have issues trying to store encrypted data as a `std::string`.  If the binary data has a 0x00 in it that would be interpreted by the `std::string` as the null terminator and truncate your encrypted data.

Comment: std::string doesn't have a null terminator, does it ? I thought that was the main reason we're using strings and not char[]s. A character array actually will truncate the data if there's a null terminator in the middle of the string.

Comment: I change `struct crypt_struct{ string name1; string name2; string name3;}` on `struct crypt_struct{ char* name1; char* name2; char* name3;}`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this:
The matter is that in the source code of this library, when decrypting, the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function is used. Those:

```
stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (struct_in.name1.c_str()), struct_in.name1.size());
```

The official documentation says:

> The pointer obtained from [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) may only be treated as a pointer to a null-terminated character string if the string object does not contain other null characters.

In the encryption function, a zero character is added to the string, and when we try to decrypt, by the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function, we trim our string with the first zero character.

But, in the standard with с++ 11, an analogous function was added that performs the same action as the [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) function, except that it does not take into account the null character.

As a result, I received:

```
stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (struct_in.name1.data()), struct_in.name1.size());
```

Also, it was important if you encrypt first `name1`, then `name2`, and `name3`. That and decrypt you should in the same sequence.

Comment: You should use something like [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) or Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) to serialize your data. You could also use the ITU's ASN.1, but its a little harder to use. After serialization then encrypt the blob.